# Proving inequalities by evaluating the lowest and highest possible value of the expression.

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, proof-verification, logarithms

This may be a possible duplicate but:

Let's say we want to prove for all $n \ge 1$:  $$\Big(1 -\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)^n \Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big) \le 1$$

We take the limit of the expression as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and set that as an upper bound (when $n$ is the highest possible); then we set the lower bound to when $n$ is the lowest possible.

I.e. if we have a function $f(n) = \Big(1 -\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)^n \Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)$, then:

$$f(1) \le f(n) \le f(\infty)$$

Evaluating the upper and lower bound we get that:

$$0 \le f(n) \le 1$$

Which is what we wanted. I am however a bit uncertain if this is a valid approach, considering that here we assume that the function is continuous and increases/decreases proportionally to increments of $n$.

My question is the following: if we prove that the function is continuous, is this then a valid way of proving the statement? Or is there something else we need to prove for this to be a valid approach?

Comment: You don't need continuous, you just need non-decreasing

Comment: Yes that makes sense, considering that then it will never fall below the lower bound once we start increasing $n$, and it will approach the upper bound in some sort of manner. This then enables us to model it the way I did.

Comment: take the logarithm on both sides

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show the function is monotone, then both extrema can occur only the boundaries.

Else for e.g. you may have something like $f(n)=\dfrac1{(n-10)^2+1}$, which has a maximum when $n=10$.  Note $f$ as a function on reals is continuous in this case, but that by itself does not mean anything wrt where maxima or minima occur.

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that $$(n-1)^n(n+1)^{n+1}\leq n^{2n+1}$$ or $f(n)\geq0$, where
$$f(x)=(2x+1)\ln{x}-x\ln(x-1)-(x+1)\ln(x+1).$$
$$f''(x)=\frac{3x-1}{x^2(x-1)^2(x+1)}>0$$ for all $x>1$ and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty} f'(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\left(\ln\frac{x^2}{x^2-1}+\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x-1}\right)=0,$$
which says $f'(x)<0$.

Thus, it's enough to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=0$, which is obvious because
$$f(x)=\ln\frac{x^{2x+1}}{(x+1)^{x+1}(x-1)^x}=\ln\frac{\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^x}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}}=\ln\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^x}{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^{x+1}}.$$

Done!

Comment: A nice proof, however I didn't ask for another proof; just verification/clarification of the one that I provided!

Comment: @Sam Anderson I did not see any proof from you. If you'll calculate an upper bound of $f$ you'll solve the problem. But why the upper bound is equal to $1$?

Comment: Because the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ of the function is $1$.

Comment: @Sam Anderson It's obvious. But why for your $f$ we have $f(n)\leq1$? You need to prove it.

Comment: I already got my answer; and it was that when the function is monotonically increasing we can do it the way I did. It doesn't matter IF the function for my example actually was that or not, I just wanted proof verification on if I'm allowed to do like that GIVEN that the function has some property (in this case if it's monotonically increasing or not). I already had another rigorous proof of the equality, which had nothing to do with this at all; a proof of the equality was not what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sam Anderson Good luck!